# How can I write an 1,4 glycosidic bond in Latex text?

Tags: spacing, arrows, chemistry

I want to write

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  %ÄÖÜß und griechische Buchstaben

\usepackage{chemfig} %Erstellen von Skelettformeln organischer Substanzen
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % \ce zum Darstellen von chemischen Formeln
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

It is a polymer consisting primarily of 1\ce{\rightarrow}\!4-linked 2-\textit{O}-sulfated \textsc{l}-iduronic acid  and 6-\textit{O}-sulfated, \textit{N}-sulfated glucosamine

\end{document}
```

But there is a space after the arrow and before the 4. How can I get rid of that space?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could you please show us the desired output?

Answer (score 5):

I'd simply write something like

```
1$\to$4
```

[image]

Actually I'd probably use [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) for the document, anyway, and define a macro for this, maybe

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\NewChemIUPAC\glycosidiclink{\ensuremath{\to}}

\newcommand*\glc[2]{#1\glycosidiclink#2}

\begin{document}

It is a polymer consisting primarily of \glc{1}{4}-linked 2-\oxygen-sulfated
\laevus-iduronic acid and 6-\oxygen-sulfated, \nitrogen-sulfated glucosamine

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the placement of the 4 with the `\kern` command:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  %ÄÖÜß und griechische Buchstaben

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % \ce zum Darstellen von chemischen Formeln

\begin{document}

It is a polymer consisting primarily of 1\ce{\rightarrow}\!{\kern-.2em{4}}-linked 2-\textit{O}-sulfated \textsc{l}-iduronic acid  and 6-\textit{O}-sulfated, \textit{N}-sulfated glucosamine

\end{document}
```

I've used a negative value of `\kern` to place the 4 further towards the arrow. You can even place it inside the arrow, with for instance `{\kern-.5em{4}}`.